# Why are recommendations about 6 player games fine, but recommendations about 8 player games get closed instantly by mods?

Tags: discussion

**[evidently, recommendations for a six player game are fine.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/276/recommendations-for-6-player-board-game)**

**[but this question about 8 players games was closed instantly](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-are-some-good-8-player-games)**

Here's the explanation that was given:

> Hola, need to tighten this up some. An
>   8-player game to solve what problem,
>   or set of conditions? As written,
>   you're looking for everything from
>   Advanced Civilization to Texas
>   Hold'em. A good question shouldn't
>   have an endless number of answers.
>   Including a number of potential
>   answers in your question makes this
>   look more suited to a forum than
>   stackexchange.

Does the 6 player question satisfy these criteria? If it does and I'm doing something wrong please help! [My second try got closed as a duplicate of the first](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/recommendations-for-an-8-player-board-game/2338#2338), even though I'd tried to improve things. :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed this qualification from the 6 player question:

> Many games can be played by 6 players, but suffer from a loss of pace, and long waits between turns. **What games have parallel planning phases, or lots of interaction during turns?**

Your question needs to be tightened up, I think, otherwise it's "List every 8 player game ever made!" which is not.. useful.

Comment: my first question includes that exact text and the second also lists similar qualifications for an acceptable answer. :D

Comment: @crazy I think your question goes in too many directions, so I edited it for brevity and re-opened.

Comment: my question goes in just as many directions as the 6-player question, unless I'm missing something. Thanks for the reopen! Lets just hope the other diamond mods loosen up a little so I don't have to ask for close explanations on meta. :P